# Itunes put random photos on my iphone I cant delete

Tags: itunes, photos, macos

Itunes put some photos from my laptop onto my  phone and now i cannot delete them please help! How do I delete them?

Comment: It cannot be random. It might be something you've set to sync through iTunes. Check with the iTunes during the syncing process under photos.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the phone to iTunes and then deselect photo sync and then sync the phone. iTunes will remove all those photos